# disable drag drop in certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problem with disabling the sortable function when the ui id is of the value "comp". I'm not too sure what have went wrong, hopefully someone can help me out here.

```
$(".sort").sortable({ // begin sortable
        connectWith: ".sort",
        receive: function(event, ui) { // begin receive
            var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
            var status = this.id;
            //alert(status);
            if(status == "comp")
            {
                alert(status),
                 $('.sort').sortable("disable");
            }
            .always(function(){
            window.location.reload();
            });
        }, // end receive
    }) // end sortable
```

Comment: provide a fiddle mate..

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than you can imagine, thanks to the [**items**](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) option in sortable plugin. In your case it will be (supposing that sortable elements are identified as `li`):

```
$(".sort").sortable({
   items: "li:not(#comp)"
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx0uhb49/)**

**EDIT**

To stop sorting a specific received element, you can update the code as follows.

```
<ul class="sort">
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem4</li>
    <li>elem5</li>
    <li>elem6</li>
</ul>

<ul class="othersort">
    <li id="comp">elem3</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the needed code for jQuery.

```
$(".sort").sortable({
   items: "li:not(#comp)"
});

$(".othersort").sortable({
   connectWith: ".sort"
});
```

The external element (`#comp`) can be dragged inside the existing list in a specific position (as you want), but when it's inside it cannot be sorted anymore.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hx0uhb49/7/)

Comment: this is what i'm aiming to achieve, the id comp belongs to the ul id. I've attached my fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/thomasli/o2g3ugvk/1/ so once it's inside the comp ul, it won't be able to sort.

Comment: @thomasli So, you want an external element to be draggable inside the list, but when it's inside the list, it must be fixed position. Am I right?

Comment: yup, that's what I'm aiming to achieve. is the logic even right to begin with?

Comment: @wrxsti thanks to the both of you, this is what I'm looking for. But why do I have to separate the 2 functions and is there any possible way to prevent the initial list item that exist in comp from getting drag? sorry for those question. this is my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thomasli/o2g3ugvk/7/

Comment: @thomasli: I'm a bit confused... you've commented my answer with a fiddle I haven't created. If my answer fits to your request and you would like to ask something about it, please post a question using fiddles I've posted. Otherwise I'm not the person you're looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to use the [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event, then you weren't too far off aside from some syntax errors. 
If you didn't want this to happen on the receive event, you could easily change that same logic to happen on any of [these events](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/). I hope this helps, and let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o2g3ugvk/9/)

Updated the code as well:

**HTML**: Give the `<li>` that you don't want to be sortable a class.

```
<ul id="comp" class="sort">
    <li class="unsortable">7</li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**: Then you can cancel that class.

```
$(".sort").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sort"
});

$(".sort").sortable({
    items: "ul:not(#comp)",
    cancel: '.unsortable'
});
```

Comment: this is what i'm aiming to achieve, the id comp belongs to the ul id. I've attached my fiddle here. jsfiddle.net/thomasli/o2g3ugvk/1 so once it's inside the comp ul, it won't be able to sort.

Comment: I think I understand now. Check that and see what you think.

Comment: Updated it to cancel out the initial <li>. I'm not 100% sure why it requires two separate calls to sortable(), but it is the only way I was able to get it to work. You could also daisy chain the two sortable methods together if you like.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Do you have any further questions? Just a follow up as I see you have not selected an answer.

Comment: yup, I managed to solved it with your help. thank you so so much, and I really appreciate it.